# How do I animate instances from their pivot point with one empty?

Tags: animation, particles, parent, empty

If you create instances of an object with a particle system, how do you then animate them from each origin point (pivot point) with one empty?

Here is a plane, parented to an empty placed at the origin of the plane. When you rotate this empty the plane rotates from its origin point:
[image]

Here is a cylinder with a particle system emitting the plane from a central ring of 8 vertices:
[image]

When I rotate the empty the particle instances also rotate correctly:
[image]

Here's the problem, when I 'Make Instances Real' in the modifier tab, the instances no longer rotate even though they are linked as duplicate instances:
[image]

How do I rotate these 'real' instances and use the empty to animate them (I will keyframe the empty to affect all instances)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your process with instances and particles, but as soon as you make your instances real they will not copy what you do to the original object.

If you want to make your instances real nevertheless, in order to get the same result you could give your objects a *Copy Rotation* constraint with an empty as *Target* and *Mix > Add*:

[image]

Rotate the empty, the objects will rotate as well:

[image]

Comment: Right, of course, simple! Thank you!